# Pyhon - Importing URL from text file and loop when code has run

Tags: python

Im kinda new to python and are stuck at something.
I made a code, that works great that logs in to a web page and scrapes the info I want from the web page and prints it.

Thing is that I want to loop it, since I have more web pages with same login info and info I want to scrape from it. The web pages I have in a list (have it in excel, but could make it a plain text file if thats easyer).
So what I want to do is take first web address from list, run it thru the code and then loop it to top where it grabs second web address and so on untill it have run thru the whole list of addresses.

Could anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Many thanks, Thomas

Comment: you're just looking for a basic for each loop

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('urls.txt', 'r') as file:
    for link in file:
        # do what you want with the link
```

[read more here](https://stackabuse.com/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert you logic to a function, then iterate over a list of sites (Loop over them). Calling the function with each individual site.

```
# if you want to use a spreadsheet
import xlrd
path = 'pathtoexcel'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0,0) # As in the first value in the first column, change for the location of the url in your spreedsheet

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
  your_logic(sheet.cell_value(i, 0)

# ==================================

# if you decide to use a text file
with open('path_to_file.txt', 'r') as f:
  urls = f.readlines()

for url in urls:
  your_logic(url) # Where 'your_logic' has you logic for scraping
```